# Where can I find a browser based editor for python that works with IE7?

Tags: python, browser, internet-explorer-7, editor

I'd like to get some code editing for a free software project done during some free time that I will have today at my university. There's just one small problem: We're almost entirely a windows environment (mostly thin clients at that) and the only source code editor installed is jGRASP.

So, I need a source code editor which is usable without installing anything (something browser, or Java Web Start based). I would use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), but I think downloading and running some unapproved exe may be in violation of our acceptable use policy, and it isn't that efficient of an editor for python anyway.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best webbased editor I know is [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/).

If you can't execute downloaded exes, this maybe mute, but [SciTe](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html) is reasonably useable and does not require you to install anything - just download and run.

Comment: It looks nice, but I don't like the fact that requires you to use git rather than allowing a simple file upload. For this project I'd prefer to  use something like launchpad because while github's git integration is excellent, their other tools (especially bug tracking) are lacking. I'll give you the check for the solution to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Putty and vim would be my solution (Requires a remote host running 'nix)

Putty is obviously a 3rd party binary, but a fairly common one.

I'm sure there are web based ssh clients to be had.

Comment: Or EMACS :P I hadn't thought of that. Thanks +1

Comment: The emacs thing is probably in jest, but editor wars get out of hand very quickly here on SO.....